# crystal report failed to get data

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, oracle11g

I'm new in crystal report I need some help:
I have been set the report Database Logon in two ways as following:

1st: rpt.SetDatabaseLogon(userId, userPassword);

2nd: DatabaseLogOn(fullserverName, dBName, dBUser, userPassword);

the first way is working well but I need to change it to the second one for some reasons but
Unfortunately it's not working and I don't know the reason:

```
public void DatabaseLogOn(string serverstring, string databasestring, string useridstring, string passwordstring)
            {
                var crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
                crConnectionInfo.ServerName = serverstring;
                crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = databasestring ;
                crConnectionInfo.UserID = useridstring ;
                crConnectionInfo.Password = passwordstring ;
                crConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = true;
                var crTableLogonInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
                Tables CrTables;
                CrTables = rpt.Database.Tables;
                foreach (Table crTable in CrTables)
                {
                    crTableLogonInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
                    crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                    crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogonInfo);

                }

            Sections CrSections = rpt.ReportDefinition.Sections;
            // loop through all the sections to find all the report objects 
            foreach (Section CrSection in CrSections)
            {
                ReportObjects CrReportObjects = CrSection.ReportObjects;
                //loop through all the report objects in there to find all subreports 
                foreach (ReportObject CrReportObject in CrReportObjects)
                {
                    if (CrReportObject.Kind == ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject)
                    {
                        SubreportObject CrSubreportObject = (SubreportObject)CrReportObject;
                        //open the subreport object and logon as for the general report 
                        ReportDocument CrSubreportDocument =      CrSubreportObject.OpenSubreport(CrSubreportObject.SubreportName);
                        CrTables = CrSubreportDocument.Database.Tables;
                        foreach (Table aTable in CrTables)
                        {
                            crTableLogonInfo = aTable.LogOnInfo;
                            crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                            aTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogonInfo);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }
```

can any one Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517974/proper-way-to-programmatically-set-database-connection-for-crystal-reports)? It is almost identical to yours and the answer to the post suggests slight changes to the structure.

Comment: Thanks campagnolo_1,
but if you observed that I'm using the same way you mentioned in the post in my method but report displayed empty in the run time although it return data in the report preview and with 1st way.

Comment: rpt.SetDatabaseLogon(userId, userPassword);  but I need to change the dbconnection in the runtime the second way is working with some reports we have in the project ... the only deference between them is the subreport in the not working report but although it's not working after removing the subreport