# Using an ODBC connection to load a Crystal Report in Code-Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a current set of code working to load a Crystal Report in c# with a server connection.

**Here's the code for loading the report:**

```
CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo.Clear();
string reportName = Request.QueryString["rpt"];
if (reportName != null)
{
    crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
    crystalReport.Load(@"\\esco-iis\crystalreports\purchasing\po.rpt");
    //crystalReport.Load(@"\\esco\crystalreports\purchasing\po.rpt");

    var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    connectionInfo.ServerName = "server";
    connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "database";
    connectionInfo.Password = "pass";
    connectionInfo.UserID = "user";
    connectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;
    crystalReport.SetDatabaseLogon("user", "pass", "server", "database");
    Tables CrTables = crystalReport.Database.Tables;
    TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
    {
        crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
        crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
        CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
        CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo.Add(crtableLogoninfo);

    }

    foreach (ReportDocument report in crystalReport.Subreports)
    {
        report.SetDatabaseLogon("user", "pass", "server", "database");
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in report.Database.Tables)
        {
            crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
            CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo.Add(crtableLogoninfo);
        }
    }

    string PO = Request.QueryString["PO"];
    if (PO != null)
    {
        ParameterField parameter = new ParameterField();
        ParameterDiscreteValue parameterValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        parameterValue.Value = PO;
        parameter.Name = "@PO";
        parameter.CurrentValues.Add(parameterValue);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo.Add(parameter);
    }
}
```

**Current state:** This works when the report is set up to connect to the database direct, but about half of them are set up to use an ODBC connection.

**Attempt:** I attempted to switch the server name to the name of the ODBC connection, but this still came back with the same `Failed to open the connection. Failed to open the connection.` error.

**Problem:** I can't seem to figure out what I can change in my ConnectionInfo to be able to make it use an ODBC connection successfully. I keep getting a  `Failed to open the connection. Failed to open the connection.`

I'm aware of the solution to do a connection separately and set the reportsource, but this isn't feasible since there are many reports.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Setting an ODBC connection at runtime is [rather](http://ta.speot.is/2012/04/28/dynamic-odbc-rdo-connection-strings-in-crystal-reports/) [tricky](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/258d7724-8907-4494-b70e-f59dd7ed5844/changing-connection-string-dynamically-at-runtime?forum=vscrystalreports), mostly because there are all these additional "logon properties" and "connection attributes" that need to be set:

> ```
> // DbConnectionAttributes contains some, but not all, consts.
> var logonProperties = new DbConnectionAttributes();
> logonProperties.Collection.Set("Connection String", @"Driver={SQL Server};Server=TODD-PC\SQLEXPRESS2;Trusted_Connection=Yes;");
> logonProperties.Collection.Set("UseDSNProperties", false);
>
> var connectionAttributes = new DbConnectionAttributes();
> connectionAttributes.Collection.Set("Database DLL", "crdb_odbc.dll");
> connectionAttributes.Collection.Set("QE_DatabaseName", String.Empty);
> connectionAttributes.Collection.Set("QE_DatabaseType", "ODBC (RDO)");
> connectionAttributes.Collection.Set("QE_LogonProperties", logonProperties);
> connectionAttributes.Collection.Set("QE_ServerDescription", @"TODD-PC\SQLEXPRESS2");
> connectionAttributes.Collection.Set("QE_SQLDB", true);
> connectionAttributes.Collection.Set("SSO Enabled", false);
>
> return new ConnectionInfo
>            {
>                Attributes = connectionAttributes,
>                // These don't seem necessary, but we'll include them anyway: ReportDocument.Load does
>                ServerName = @"TODD-PC\SQLEXPRESS2",
>                Type = ConnectionInfoType.CRQE
>            };
> ```

---

On the other hand, rather than creating a `ConnectionInfo` object from scratch, you might be able to use the existing one, especially if you already designed your report using a similar connection:

```
foreach (Table crTable in crTables)
{
    TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
    var connectionInfo = tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo;

    // set connection info stuff here

    crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogOnInfo);
}
```

Comment: @oppassum: Well, I specifically see a line in your code that uses `new ConnectionInfo();`

Comment: Tried it your way. No difference.

Answer (score 2):

For legacy reports with SQL Server ODBC, using "SQL Server Native Driver 11.0" might be needed.

```
class CrystalDatabase
    {

        public static TableLogOnInfo GetODBCTableLogOnInfo(string ODBCName, string serverName, string databaseName, string userID, string password)
        {
            CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag connectionAttributes = new CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag();

            connectionAttributes.EnsureCapacity(3);
            connectionAttributes.Add(DbConnectionAttributes.CONNINFO_CONNECTION_STRING, string.Format("DSN={0};Driver={{SQL Server}}", ODBCName));
            connectionAttributes.Add("Server", serverName);
            connectionAttributes.Add("UseDSNProperties", false);

            DbConnectionAttributes attributes = new DbConnectionAttributes();
            attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("Database DLL", "crdb_odbc.dll"));
            attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("QE_DatabaseName", databaseName));
            attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("QE_DatabaseType", "ODBC (RDO)"));
            attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("QE_LogonProperties", connectionAttributes));
            attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("QE_ServerDescription", serverName));
            attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("QE_SQLDB", true));
            attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("SSO Enabled", false));

            ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = GetConnectionInfo(serverName, databaseName, userID, password);
            connectionInfo.Attributes = attributes;
            connectionInfo.Type = ConnectionInfoType.CRQE;
            connectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;
            TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
            tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
            return tableLogOnInfo;
        }

        public static ConnectionInfo GetConnectionInfo(string serverName, string databaseName, string userID, string password)
        {
            ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
            connectionInfo.ServerName = serverName;
            connectionInfo.DatabaseName = databaseName;
            connectionInfo.UserID = userID;
            connectionInfo.Password = password;

            return connectionInfo;
        }
    }
```

This class should be combined with an implementation similar to this: [crystal report failed to get data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031759/crystal-report-failed-to-get-data)